# Wildcard for any value including blank

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

According to [COUNTIF the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480),

> `criterion` can contain wildcards including `?` to match any single character or `*` to match zero or more contiguous characters.

But this is incorrect because `*` doesn't match an empty cell.

How can I match any value, including blank?

Comment: In the title you was mentioned `SUMIFS` but the link points to `COUNTIF`. What formula are you trying? Besides the formula please add some sample input data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `*` doesn't work because an empty cell does not have zero characters; it's basically 'undefined'. It does not match any `COUNTIF` criterion you can think of. This is how it's intended to be used: `Test*` matches both 'Test' and 'Test2':

[image]

To count empty cells, you'll need [`COUNTBLANK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093403):

[image]